# ¿Como crear un archivo excel con Node Js y Vue?

Tags: nodejs, excel, vue.js

Necesito ayuda, deseo crear un archivo excel con node js.Actualmente estoy trabajando node.js, vue.js y Vuetify. 
La informacion es consultada desde una api externa, la cual no tengo el codigo y si la consulto me envia como respuestas en formato JSON.
Aqui un ejemplo de la respuesta que recibo.

```
[
{
    "total": 0,
    "estado": 1,
    "eliminar": 1,
    "_id": "5e627023b41f9913e4cb0f31",
    "nroVale": 1011,
    "cliente": {
        "_id": "5e5e9101dc22821b041057dd",
        "nombre": "Solicitante de Prueba"
    },
    "usuario": {
        "_id": "5e62472fb41f9913e4cb0f30",
        "nombre": "Encargado de Prueba"
    },
    "otVale": "BR-102",
    "comentario": "Es un comentario de Pruba",
    "equipo": {
        "_id": "5e60f7b23c702d1fe0bf1526",
        "nombre": "Sin Equipo"
    },
    "productos": [
        {
            "_id": "5e4af46ad7fab94d8625705d",
            "codigo": "1",
            "unidad": "UN",
            "conversor": "0",
            "tipoConversor": "0",
            "descripcion": "Manguera",
            "cantidad": 10
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e4af448d7fab94d86256ef1",
            "codigo": "3",
            "unidad": "UN",
            "conversor": "0",
            "tipoConversor": "0",
            "descripcion": "Vaso  ",
            "cantidad": 10
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e4af448d7fab94d86256ef3",
            "codigo": "5",
            "unidad": "UN",
            "conversor": "0",
            "tipoConversor": "0",
            "descripcion": "Torta  ",
            "cantidad": 16
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e4af448d7fab94d86256ef4",
            "codigo": "11",
            "unidad": "BL",
            "conversor": "0",
            "tipoConversor": "0",
            "descripcion": "Sillas ",
            "cantidad": 18
        }
    ],
    "Local": {
        "_id": "5e569e05f6316f1940225903",
        "nombre": "Casa Central"
    },
    "empresa": {
        "_id": "5e569e8df6316f1940225906",
        "nombre": "Externo Prueba"
    },
    "actividad": {
        "_id": "5e56a6478fc37f4180fca309",
        "nombre": "Fiesta de Cumpleaño"
    },
    "fecha": "2020-03-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "centroCosto": {
        "_id": "5e46b42a8ee91743a0c9230d",
        "nombre": "Pago Efectivo"
    },
    "Payaso": {
        "_id": "5e46b42a8ee91743a0c9230d",
        "nombre": "Gorrito"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

]

Yo recibo esta informacion en formato JSON y la almaceno en un array y este array necesito transformarlo en formato .xlsx o  excel

Si tuvieran un ejemplo para asi tomar una idea, se los agradeceria demasiado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la libreria XLSX puedes exportarlo de forma sencilla: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Un codigo de ejemplo: this.data debe ser un array que contenga tus datos.

```
exportar() {
    let data = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.data);
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const filename = "planilla";
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, data, filename);
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${filename}.xlsx`);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda 7u7